# Query on jquery if and :contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why the below if statement does not give me the desired results. Every time it just give me a yellow paragraph even though the concerned word does not satisfy the :contains expression. I am pasting the query below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("p:contains(x)")) {
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p class="hand">This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>glow</p>
  <p>The heading, paragraph and button element have a click event defined. Click on each element to display which element triggered the event.</p>
  <div style="color:blue;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see a reference to the variable x - so I just made it up :). The following determines is the string "glow" is in the p and makes the background yellow. Any p that does not contain "glow" has a background colour of red. I would however suggest adding / removing classes rather than adjusting the CSS directly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains('glow')").css("background-color", "yellow"); 
  $("p").not(":contains('glow')").css("background-color", "red");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p class="hand">This is a paragraph</p>
<p>glow</p>
<p>The heading, paragraph and button element have a click event defined. Click on each element to display which element triggered the event.</p>
<div style="color:blue;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use condition means you have to check whether the value of `length` is greater than 0. other wise you can simply use

```
$("p").css("background-color", "red");
$("p:contains(glow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

which sets the background color for all paragraph as red and the selected one as yellow

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("p:contains(glow)").length > 0) {
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
    $("p:contains(glow)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p class="hand">This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>glow</p>
  <p>The heading, paragraph and button element have a click event defined. Click on each element to display which element triggered the event.</p>
  <div style="color:blue;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```